# Binding with custom text in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, text, binding

Can i write something like this in WPF(i know that this piece of code is wrong, but need to know if there is kind of this construct):

```
<TextBlock Height="50" Text="Test: {Binding Path=MODULE_GUID}" />
```

Or always to add some text to binding value i must do something like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
   <TextBlock Height="50" Text="Test: " />
   <TextBlock Height="50" Text="{Binding Path=MODULE_GUID}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with .NET 3.5 SP1, you can use:

```
<TextBlock Height="50" Text="{Binding Path=MODULE_GUID, StringFormat='Test: {0}'}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use StringFormat in the Binding

Answer (score 1):

Simply use string format in Binding

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MODULE_GUID, StringFormat='Your Text Goes Here {0}'}" />
```

Remember `{0}`
 must be there.